# multidimensional array with only one value, how to get properly the value?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I work with a CMS (Drupal 8). It automatically generates some multidimensional array with an unique value, like this :

```
//var_dump of my $array
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'value' => string '50' (length=2)
```

To date, I use this ugly way for automatically get the value (in example : "50") of these arrays :

```
array_shift(array_values(array_shift(array_values($array))))
```

My question is, is there a better way in php for get that ?

Comment: `$array[0]['value']` ??

Comment: Nah, I would agree with him.  That's pretty ugly.  It's not elegant and it's clunky to read.

Comment: Yes, use $array[0]['value'] is pretty ugly. In addition, nothing tells me that the "0" or the 'value' will change for some unexpected reason. My approach "array_shift(array_values(array_shift(array_values(" is little uglier but more generic. But maybe there isn't no other ways ? :/

Comment: Your statement generates the following error in all versions of PHP from 5.3 to 7.0 `Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference`

Comment: `$array[0]['value']` is FAR more straight forward to read than the stacked `array_values(array_shift())` code you got going on.  But yeah, `reset` is your best point of action at this point if you are not sure that `$array` will always have index of 0.  Although it does appear that it's not an associative array so it could be safe to use `$array[$index]['value']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you know it's an array in an array?

```
$value = reset(reset($array));
```

You don't know how many <strike>turtles</strike> arrays are nested?

```
$value = $array;
while(is_array($value))
    $value = reset($array);
```

[Docs on reset](http://php.net/reset)

Answer (score 0):

Just use via index:

```
$array[0]['value']
```